# Custom SQL Query passing array to WHERE p.id

Tags: query, wpdb

I need to pass an array of post ID's to a custom SQL query I am running on a certain page.

The query looks like this:

```
$querystr3 = "SELECT *, 
    events_startdate.meta_value AS the_start,
    events_enddate.meta_value AS the_end
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships 
        ON ( p.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id )
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
        ON ( $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_startdate 
        ON ( 
            p.ID = events_startdate.post_id 
            AND events_startdate.meta_key = 'events_startdate' 
        )
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_enddate 
        ON(
            p.ID = events_enddate.post_id 
            AND events_enddate.meta_key = 'events_enddate' 
    ) 
    WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 11
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'status'
        AND p.ID != array(1433, 1344) <--- trying to pass array here
        AND p.post_type = 'pmg_events'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND events_startdate.meta_value != ''
        AND events_enddate.meta_value != ''
        AND events_enddate.meta_value >= CURDATE()
    )
    ORDER BY events_enddate.meta_value ASC
";      
$theresults3 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr3 );
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass 2 post ID's to exclude from a custom SQL query I am running. If I pass in one number ie: p.ID != 1433 it works, but passing in multiple post ID's does not.

I've tried using `implode(',',$ids);` but still to no avail. Is it not possible to pass in an array like this. I don't want to re-write this to use `$wp_query`.

Comment: For future questions: Please format your code so people don't have to scroll just to read it.

Comment: Aside from the formatting issues: What you are trying to do is a `date_query()` with an additional `tax_query()` (based on meta values). Why don't you do that? Just because above _somehow_ works? Btw, a MySQL Array just is a list of comma separated values in round brackets... example: `(do,not,be,lazy,reformat,to,wpdb,to,safe,yourself,troubles,on,the,long,run)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a SQL question then a WordPress question.

Here are some ideas:

- You're most likely looking for this kind of structure:

  ```
  AND p.ID NOT IN (1433, 1344)
  ```
- You should consider using `$wp->prepare()` if your query depends on some user input.
- You might also want to replace `CURDATE()` with a PHP generated date string, to see if it gives you any performance gain.
- In general it's more flexible to use the `WP_Query()` when possible, to avoid such hardcoded SQL bastards ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response birgire. Unfortunately I didn't write this chunk of code. A previous developer had, and they want to keep the queries the same for some reason. If It were up to me I'd re-write it using WP_Query as I'm much more comfortable writing that than straight SQL queries

Comment: Hi EHerman, good luck taming it and hopefully it won't bite you ;-)